Transform a recursive sequence to a iterative sequence
Consider the sequence $x_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}y_{n-j}x_j$ with $x_0=1$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N\backslash 0}$ is any arbitrary sequence. Show that
\begin{align*}
x_n=\sum_{j=0}^n a_{nj}
\end{align*}
where $a_{nj}=\sum_{k=j-1}^{n-1}y_{n-k}a_{k,j-1}$
with $a_{k0}=0$ for $k=1,\dots$ and $a_{00}=1$.
My idea is to show this with induction. I already showed it to $n=0$ and $n=1$, but I have problems to show the induction step. I started with $x_{n+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\sum_{k=j-1}^{n}y_{n+1-k}a_{k,j-1}$ but now I don't know how to apply the induction hypothesis. Is induction a good idea or is there another way to prove this statement? Thanks for help

Let $n$ be any natural number and suppose that the required equality is proved for
all nonnegative integers $k<n$. Then
$$\sum_{j=0}^n a_{nj}=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{nj}=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=j-1}^{n-1}y_{n-k}a_{k,j-1}=$$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} y_{n-k} \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} a_{k,j-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} y_{n-k} \sum_{i=0}^k a_{k,i}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} y_{n-k} x_k=x_n.$$
